# Backpress in jetpack compose doesn't work with LocalSoftwareKeyboardController

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, onbackpressed

I have an activity with LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.
And then push back press, he close only keyboard, second click on back press do nothing.
Tried BackHandler and tried in inCreate:

```
        onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this, object: OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
            override fun handleOnBackPressed() {

            }
        })
```